# How to enforce to provide params in ng resource?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

Is there a way to not call or cancell ng resource endpoint call if parameter is not provided?

```
function endpointCallService($rootScope, $resource) {
  return $resource('some-url', null, {
    getSome: {
      url: 'some-url/:param/some-url-continue',
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        param: '@param'
      }
    }
  });
}
```

any of action methods from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) doesn't seem to help me.
I know I could validate it before making a call, but in my case it would be easier to make it here.
If there is a lack of `param`, then it calls `some-url/some-url-continue` and I don't want it.